# Entity framework IDENTITY_INSERT

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The 'Category'  table in database defined like this:

```
CategoryID - PK ,identity specification ON  (only this column has identity)   
Description  
Title
```

I want to insert new data:

```
Category cat = new Category
{
    Description = "xxx",
    Title = "yyy",
};
if (cat.EntityState == EntityState.Detached)
{
   Articlerctx.AddToCategories(cat);
}
return Articlerctx.SaveChanges();
```

I get error:

> Cannot insert explicit value for
>   identity column in table 'Categories'
>   when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

But I am not inserting the CategoryID! I want it to receive auto value!

Comment: Thanks, the problem was with model updating! Write it as answer and i will accept it :)

Comment: OK, done - made my comments into an answer - thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your scenario works just fine in my case - using EF4.

Check the following things:

- have you changed your database model since you first created your Entity model, and if so, have you really updated your entity model??
- is your `cat.EntityState` really `detached` at that point in time?? In my case, when using EF4 with an `ObjectContext`, it is `Added`. In that case, you wouldn't be adding the new `Cat` object to the categories collection..

Answer (score 6):

Your mapping is wrong. The `StoreGeneratedPattern` on `CategoryID` *should* be set to `Identity`, but you have it set to `None`. Fix that.

Comment: can you please clarify your answer? "StoreGeneratedPattern"

Comment: @asker: Click the property (`CategoryId`) in the designer. Look at the Properties window. Change the `StoreGeneratedPattern` value. Or Google that word.

Comment: @CraigStuntz : How the HELL did you know this??? How did you know this was even an issue? If this is a common problem, why does it arise when the Model is auto-generated? I spent a day trying to attach my entity until I came across this little answer...thank you.

Comment: @SpaceRach: "An expert is a man who has made all the mistakes that can be made in a very narrow field." — Niels Bohr